# SQL : Group by with case to set values for both conditions

Tags: sql, case, datepart, maxdate

**Pre Condition:** [I am using Week as Sunday as first day of week]
I have table '#TT' as below

```
Column -> D_Date
----------
2020-12-27 |
2020-12-28 |
2020-12-29 |
2020-12-30 |
2020-12-31 |
2021-01-01 |
2021-01-02 |
```

I want to get week numbers for date And in case of year end with new year start, I want to mark the first week as 0 for new year if it's days contribution is less than 4 days i.e.

As per US week

```
2020-12-27 from this **53rd** start
2020-12-28
2020-12-29
2020-12-30
2020-12-31
2021-01-01
2021-01-02  and end at here
```

In above from 27 till 31 are 5 days of 2020 whereas for 1 and 2 of 2021 are 2 days, thus majority days are from 2020 and not 2021.
Now I want to mark week number for 2021 as 0 for dates 1 & 2 and not 1

I am using below query but it is decreasing my minimum year's week number too. How to achieve this? Please help me.

```
SELECT
    
    DATEPART( week, D_Date ),
    
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT( DATEPART( week, D_Date ) ) > 1 THEN MAX( DATEPART(week, D_Date ) - 1 ) 
        ELSE DATEPART( week, D_Date )
   END AS [State]
FROM
    #tt
GROUP BY
    DATEPART( year, D_Date ),
    DATEPART( week, D_Date );
```

Comment: Exactly what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Have you considered using `DATEPART( iso_week, ... )` to get the week-number?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2017

Comment: Problem is when year ends and new year start and scenario happened where new year's day in week from [Sunday - Saturday] is having days less than 4 then those days of previous year's count i.e. 2020-12-27, 28, 29, 30, 31 are 5 days and 2021-01-01, 02 are only 2 days thus first week of 2021 will start from 2021-01-03.
So DATEPART( week, D_Date ) function is bringing 2021-01-01 and 02 as week 1 but I need some mechanism so that this should be counted as week 0 and week 1 should be counted for day 2021-01-03 to 2021-01-09.
For this one year I can do it but using -1 but I need it for any range